# Flutter ios shared preference show setstring on null error

Tags: ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

I have my flutter application whereupon login I called shared preference to store some value e.g. token, user ID, etc. All this while it worked both on ios and android well. Suddenly now on ios, it's giving me NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setString' was called on null

Here is the code snippet.

```
try {
          //final jsonResponse = json.decode(responseJson);
          Login login1 = new Login.fromJson(responseJson);
          token = login1.token;
          print(login1.fleetID);

          await AuthUtils.insertDetails(_sharedPreferences, responseJson);
        } catch (Err) {
          print("ERrro is at" + Err.toString());
        }
The whole of this function it self is async.

Below is the function where I call the to insert details.

static insertDetails(SharedPreferences prefs, var response) async {     
    print("Token is :"+response['token']);
    print("userID is :"+response['userID']);    

    await prefs.setString(authTokenKey, response['token']);
        await prefs.setString(userIdKey, response['userID']);   

    }
```

I have printed both the token and userID are not empty or null. But I still get the error message of '***setString***' was called on null. But it works perfectly fine on Android only ios

Just to add on I found this below.

> Receiver: null Tried calling: setString("auth_token",
>   "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1NTc2MDAzNTcsImV4cCI6MTU1NzYwNjM1NywianRpIjoiNmExOE9CTE9m")

Comment: You've asked the same question on gitter, and provided more details there. Without those details it would be difficult to answer this question as written. Please always update your question with other relevant details as they become available.

Comment: @RichardHeap sorry for my lack of information here but now I got a new error as below I have put in the comment of your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `insertDetails` you are passing in a `null` for `prefs`, so when you try to do `prefs.setString` it fails.

Piecing together other details from your gitter questions, this is because the value that you are passing isn't initialised (yet).

You have over-complicated things. You have a member variable

```
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

that's simply not doing anything. `SharedPreferences` is a singleton, so there's no harm in just obtaining a reference whenever you need it.

Also of note is that it isn't necessary to wait for the result of `.setString()` on shared preferences. The new value is written into the in-memory cache immediately and a native request is dispatched to the Android or iOS layer to commit it to storage.

Refactor `insertDetails` like this:

```
  static insertDetails(var response) async {
    print('Token is : ${response['token']}');
    print('userID is : ${response['userID']}');

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(authTokenKey, response['token']);
    prefs.setString(userIdKey, response['userID']);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Now I have tried your method like this await AuthUtils.insertDetails(responseJson); but I end up getting a new error that is MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: should I lodge this a bug into github for this issue?

Comment: That is strange. Thousands of apps including mine work fine and don't show that. It's very unlikely to be a bug. Try cloning the source repo and run the example app before reporting it.

Comment: yes this is very strange and you know it works perfectly fine on Android with the same codes. To your surprise what I did I build a new project and then I copy over manually my codes and now the new project with my codes are working fine with no issue.

Comment: glad you got it going - if the answer was useful, don't forget to accept it - thanks

Comment: thank you for your help. I hope it wont be giving another weird issue. Yes I have accepted your answer.